# Autohotkey AppsKey does not work properly in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, autohotkey, context-menu

I try the following hotkey in Chrome:

```
!F3::Send {AppsKey}{Up}
```

Chrome opens the context menu but it doesn't move the selected line in the context menu. Instead the `{Up}` command moves the scroll bar up.

I tried this hotkey in another application it works as expected. Namely, the `{Up}` command moves the selected line in the context menu.

What should I do to move the selected line in the context menu of Chrome by using Autohotkey?

Answer (score 0):

It is usually necessary to wait a few milliseconds after opening a content menu so the keys are sent when the focus is actually on the context menu. So, you can play around with the [Sleep](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Sleep.htm) command until you find an acceptable time (I used `100` milliseconds in my example):

```
!F3::
    Send, {AppsKey}
    Sleep, 100
    Send, {Up}
    return
```